# How to dynamically set the id attribute of a HTML element?

Tags: javascript

I have a table and its data are generate by a Java Server page and I want to set the `tr` id attribute by selecting a row using JavaScript:

```
<tr>  // this is id attribute i want to set 
   <td>data</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Why do you want to change the id and not say add a css class\use the selected row id for something?

Comment: You want to set the `id` of how many table-rows? With what `id`, how does the `id` relate to the table-row element?

Comment: Please include a small example what javascript code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only (or the first) `<tr>` on your page, this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].id = "the_id";
<script>
```

If the table has multiple rows, this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var i = 0;
while (i<trs.length)
{
    trs[i].id = "the_id_"+i;
    i++;
}
<script>
```

Comment: Just a remark: It will work for the first `tr` element found in the DOM.